# How to load images on gridview with a small delay on scroll?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-image

I use picasso and viewholder pattern to load images in my gridview, however the gridview doesn't load smooth enough when I scroll.  How can I achieve that when i scroll the gridview only loads the placeholders first, and when every image is loaded on the given "page" the gridview shows the images  one by one in order with a small delay. Is there a better tool then picasso for that? I searched for solution,but i couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if it is possible to wait till every image is loaded on the given page. However in one of my "pet" project I have implemented the logic that - shows the placeholder and when the image is loaded it shows the actual image (however NOT when ALL the images on the page, it works with each image separately). To load the Images with the Picasso I have used the next code:

```
private def prepareImageView(image: ImageView,
                             course: Course) = {
    Picasso.`with`(context).cancelTag(image)
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_session_placeholder)
    Picasso.`with`(context)
        .load(course.imgUri)
        .tag(image)
        .into(new Target {

            override def onBitmapFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable): Unit = {}

            override def onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable): Unit = {}

            override def onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap, from: LoadedFrom): Unit = {
              image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
              image.invalidate
            }
    }
}
```

Code is in Scala, however I do not think that will be any problems to convert it to Java. At first I am setting the placeholder image to the imageView so the user sees the placeholder(R.drawable.img_session_placeholder), later Picasso will update it with the real image as soon as it's been downloaded. Also do not forget to cancel any current image download associated with the current ImageView.

This solution gives a fast scroll (since the local placeholder are used). However if the scroll is not fast still, probably there are other problems in the logic that builds each view.